# Fetch query string from inside a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two or more widgets in one page with a remote call. For example:

```
<script async src="https://example.com/widget.js?cid=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="cid_2"></div>

<script async src="https://example.com/widget.js?cid=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="cid_3"></div>
```

Inside each `widget.js` I need to take the `cid` parameter, do some tasks inside the widget that need the `cid` parameter and write the result on the corresponding `<div>` (`#cid_2`, `#cid_3` etc).

How do I get the `cid` value from the url (`.js?cid=`) from inside `widget.js`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: No duplicate  please read my example is not the same.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get something, but my first impression is very negative: this is loading the same javascript file several times, one for each widget. Terrible. Load the JS once, and then add `script` tags to call a function for each widget. May I also suggest Google Analytics code as a clever way to embed JS with great flexibility: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Answer (score 0):

i have found a way to do this getting from script src and decoding with a function. this is the example:

```
//Function to get parameters from script src
function getSRCparameter(sParam) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var index = scripts.length - 1;
    var myScript = scripts[index];
    // myScript now contains our script object
    var queryString = myScript.src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,'');

    var sPageURL = queryString,
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

//Example code
$(document).ready(function(){

    //parameter in the src
    var getValue = getSRCparameter("cid"); 

    //test results in console
    console.log("my get value is: "+getValue); 

    //put the info inside the divs
    $("#cid_"+getValue).html("ID Get is:"+getValue);
});
```

Comment: But OP wants to fetch the query string from inside the `.js` file. Getting the `src` for the `<script>` tag isn't what's being requested :x

Comment: thats is an example to get the parameter inside his own JS (widget.js) so he need to add the function inside... i already tested creating a empty widget.js

Comment: Oh yeah, I suppose since it'll be added to the DOM, it should work. My bad.

Comment: mhhh m8 thx all but i need to fetch inside my widget.js suppos that i have severla scripts in destination web side i need a method to address exactly my script

Answer (score 0):

Read from `window.location.href` after the question mark, split by `"&"` and find the parameter whose part before the `"="` matches your criteria.

```
var parameters = window.location.href.split("?")[1].split["&"];
for (var index in parameters) {
    var param = parameters[index].split("=");
    if (param[0] === "cid") {
        //Do something
    }
}
```